# Parsing json data.how can i parse this json data?

Tags: android

I am trying to parse it but i can not do that.please help me to solve it with full code in android

```
[{"Trip":{"id":"1","trip_start":"2016-05-22 17:20:06","trip_end":"2016-05-22 17:22:19"}}]
```

Comment: please Post what you try?

Comment: *but i can not do that,please help me to solve it with full code in android* We are not here to write code for nothing, show us your efforts. Do you have a [MCVE] to illustrate?

Comment: i am trying to parse this and want to show it in two text view

Comment: @Ashraf_Taukir plz send your webservice url

Comment: http://amarride.com/amarride/api/tripHistoryAction

Comment: key value is "user_id" value is 78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of Google results that would show this but it would be something like

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[{"Trip":{"id":"1","trip_start":"2016-05-22 17:20:06","trip_end":"2016-05-22 17:22:19"}}]");
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

JSONObject tripObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Trip");

Log.d("JSONResponse", "ID: " + tripObject.getString("id"));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("[{"Trip":{"id":"1","trip_start":"2016-05-22 17:20:06","trip_end":"2016-05-22 17:22:19"}}]"); i am not clear about this line why you use this json in JSONOBJECT???

Comment: @Ashraf_Taukir : Yes, It is the response JSON from the web service which needs to be parsed.

Comment: sorry it's not working i think json array is missing here

Comment: @Ashraf_Taukir : Yes it will not work. You must use JSONArray. I have edited the answer, waiting for Boardy's approval.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like its already approved, didn't notice it was a JSONObject inside a JSONArray, but yea that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String jsonResponse = "[{\"Trip\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"trip_start\":\"2016-05-22 17:20:06\",\"trip_end\":\"2016-05-22 17:22:19\"}}]";
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject tripObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Trip");

        Log.d("JSONResponse", "ID: " + tripObject.getString("id"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This approach is good when the JSON to be parsed is small. If the JSON is large you must use JSONReader. Go through this document for more details : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject tripObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONObject data=tripObject.getJSONObject("Trip");
                            String trip_start = data.getString("trip_start");
                            textView3.setText(trip_start);
                            String trip_end = data.getString("trip_end");
                            textView7.setText(trip_end);   I want to show this two value in this text view but i can't can you help me???

Comment: Your code for parsing the JSON is right. Try to print the Strings : trip_start and trip_end in logcat and tell me the output.

Comment: Add these lines to your code : Log.d("JSONResponse", "ID: " + tripObject.getString("id"));
            Log.d("JSONResponse", "Trip Start: " + tripObject.getString("trip_start"));
            Log.d("JSONResponse", "Trip End: " + tripObject.getString("trip_end"));

Comment: your answer is ok :)